# Prettyphoto and event click on iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, onclick, frame, prettyphoto

uuI'm trying to detect a click event inside an iframe. I already found some (not working) solution on SO, and I wasn't able to fix them and get them working on my code.

How can I detect the target of a click event INSIDE a iframe?

Since PrettyPhoto is simply loaded by

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
```

I was hoping for a solution similar to

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto(
     $('#myframe').bind('click', function(event) {
          alert("cliked");
     })
);
```

but this doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

use `.on()`

```
$('#myframe').on('click', function(event) {
       alert("cliked");
})
```

Comment: this does not work... I already tried live(), on(), bind(), none of them works

Answer (score 0):

You can put this outside of `prettyphoto();` and if you are using latest jquery then use `.on()` handler:

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
$('#myframe').on('click', function(event) {
      alert("cliked");
});
```

Comment: I already tried live(), on(), bind(), none of them works.
I also tried putting the handler outside PrettyPhoto initialization, but nothing changed the result..

Comment: better to post html also at your post question.

Comment: html doesn't matter. Everything needed is in my first post. html is just html (when you click a link, the iframe is showed with prettyPhoto), my problem is with jquery and iframe.. How can I handle from my main page, a click on the page in the iframe?